# Is there an R function for finding and displaying the most recent date in a row among multiple columns?

Tags: r, sorting, date

I'm sorting through invasive species data by site, and trying to figure out which record is the most recent per-site; this would allow me to categorize the site as either in-treatment, eradicated, or unknown.

Is there a way to populate a `Recent_Date` column by comparing the dates between multiple columns in one row?

| TARGET_FID | Treatment_Date | Presence_Date | Non_Detection_Date | Recent_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-30 | 2016-07-10 | 2021-10-05 | ????-??-?? |
| 2 | 2019-05-31 | 2021-06-01 | *NA* | ????-??-?? |

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Recent_Date = invoke(pmax, 
       c(across(ends_with('_Date'), as.Date), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
TARGET_FID Treatment_Date Presence_Date Non_Detection_Date Recent_Date
1          1     2021-09-30    2016-07-10         2021-10-05  2021-10-05
2          2     2019-05-31    2021-06-01               <NA>  2021-06-01
```

---

Or use `exec`

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with('_Date'), as.Date),
   Recent_Date = exec(pmax, !!! rlang::syms(names(.)[-1]), na.rm = TRUE ))
  TARGET_FID Treatment_Date Presence_Date Non_Detection_Date Recent_Date
1          1     2021-09-30    2016-07-10         2021-10-05  2021-10-05
2          2     2019-05-31    2021-06-01               <NA>  2021-06-01
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$Recent_Date <- do.call(pmax, c(df1[-1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(TARGET_FID = 1:2, Treatment_Date = c("2021-09-30", 
"2019-05-31"), Presence_Date = c("2016-07-10", "2021-06-01"), 
    Non_Detection_Date = c("2021-10-05", NA)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Something funky was happening with your first solution for me, but I used the `base R` function successfully.

Comment: @FateSigh It could be a difference in versions of dplyr/purrr packages.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Define `pmaxNA` to be the same as `pmax` except `na.rm=TRUE`.  Then we can apply it to the columns of `df1`, except the first, using `Reduce`.

```
library(dplyr)

pmaxNA <- function(...) pmax(..., na.rm = TRUE)
df1 %>% mutate(Recent_Date = Reduce(pmaxNA, across(-1)))
```

**2)** Another approach is that on each row apply `max` to all columns except the first.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(Recent_Date = max(c_across(-1), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   ungroup
```

**3)** Another way is to convert to long form and then use `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  arrange(TARGET_FID) %>%
  mutate(Recent_Date = pivot_longer(., -1) %>% 
    drop_na %>% 
    group_by(TARGET_FID) %>% 
    slice_max(value) %>% 
    pull(value)
  )
```